# GWT designer size limitation

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer

I am designing a home page by using the GWT designer.But when I reached the height of more than 600 the images are not displayed.I have placed some images and run the application then it will show.But in the design mode it is not visible.Is there any such limitation in the size ?.I am unable to align the text in the footer which is obviously at the end ....

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of GWT Designer. There's no way around this limitation so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known operating system limitation (it won't render anything larger than the physical display). Use a larger physical (or virtual) display.